# How to get from Bonifacio to Bastia via Calvi?

Tags: public-transport, france, car-rentals, buses, corsica

I've read that public transportation on Corsica is quite poor. According to rome2rio, there is one bus daily from [Calvi to Bastia](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Calvi/Bastia), but there are no results for [Bonifacio to Calvi](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bonifacio-France/Calvi).

Is the only way to get around on the island by car?

Comment: Get a car to enjoy the island as much as possible. The traffic isn't that bad anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are definitely more buses than that (not a lot more, but still), at least in the summer when there are a lot of tourists around, but information is difficult to find on the Internet. There are many different companies and they don't all have up-to-date schedules on their website.

The site [Corsica Bus](http://www.corsicabus.org/) seeks to gather information about public transport in Corsica and has information in both English and French. I recommend reading their [“Corsica without a car” page](http://www.corsicabus.org/sansVoiture.html).

From [Calvi to Bastia](http://www.corsicabus.org/busCalvi/CLY_Bastia.html), they list two buses a day in the summer (late June to early September), taking a little over 2 hours. In the winter there's only a single weekday bus. Alternatively there is a [train](http://www.cf-corse.fr/), taking a little over 3 hours, with 2 connections a day at different times in [summer](http://cf-corse.fr/DATA_CENTER/00013/medias/0567759001433152365.pdf) and [winter](http://cf-corse.fr/DATA_CENTER/00013/medias/0180267001421930010.pdf).

From [Bonifacio to Calvi](http://www.corsicabus.org/busCalvi/CLY_Bonifacio.html), it's not so good. The only suggestion is a combination of three buses, the last one being the Bastia to Calvi bus — Bonifacio-Bastia-Calvi would be easier than Bonifacio-Calvi-Bastia. You'd take the early morning or midday [bus from Bonifacio to Porto Vecchio](http://corsicabus.org/busPVecchio/PVE_Bonifacio.html) (do check because that company haven't announced their July schedule yet!), then [the Bastia bus](http://www.corsicabus.org/busPVecchio/PVE_Bastia.html) and change as Casamozza for the [bus to Calvi](http://www.corsicabus.org/busCalvi/CLY_Bastia.html), taking about 5 hours total.